# Should we merge the [amp] and [amplifiers] tags and change the name to [amplifier]

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have 2 tags for amplifier.  I propose we rename the [amplifiers] tag to [amplifier] and merge in the [amp] tag.

**Update:**

I changed everything tagged [amp] to [amplifiers].  Still need to rename [amplifiers] to [amplifier]

The only way I can find to rename a tag is to create one with the desired name and retag all questions removing the old tag and adding the new.  If someone else has the time please feel free to retag them (currently 25 questions).  If not, I'll get to it in a couple of weeks when I get back from vacation.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds good.  Would it make any difference to maintain [amp](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amp) as a synonym of a new [amplifier](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifier)?  Or perhaps that wouldn't really make a difference as the auto-complete feature kind of moves you past those three letters anyway?

As it stands now, there are only 6 tagged [amp](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amp), two of which are also tagged [amplifiers](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifiers).

Comment: I find it is usually better to be explicit to avoid confusion, especially when auto-complete is available.

Comment: I think I would agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This would just avoid confusion overall. Some of the tags could be construed different ways since this forum is unique in that it covers two very different fields `:)`

I actually have a few tags that I wanted to merge but don't have the power to yet.

Answer (score 0):

Important to keep the tags cleaned up - sounds good